# How to Include CSS and JS in Twig-View on Slim?

Tags: twig, slim-3

I am trying to include my CSS and JS files on my `Twig` template like this

```
{% block stylesheets %}
   <link href="{{ asset('bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
   <script src="{{ asset('jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js') }}"></script>
   <script src="{{ asset('popper.min.js') }}"></script>
   <script src="{{ asset('bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>        
{% endblock %}
```

I get an error on Slim like this

```
Unknown "asset" function.
```

How do I include my `CSS` and `JS` files in `Twig` via `Slim`?

Answer (score 4):

There’s no such function by default. Either install an [Asset extension](https://packagist.org/?q=slim%20twig%20assets) or hardcore links by yourself.

Comment: Thanks. But, it is not compatible with latest version of Twig-View.

Comment: Yeah, looks like the author of the repo does not know what he's doing. Have you tried using `kriswallsmith/assetic` directly? It's not so hard to add new Twig function.

Comment: No, Will try it.

Btw needed one clarification, will there be a significant decrease in size and page load times if i bundle the asset with a Twig Extension v/s using a CDN?

I'm trying to implement a complete server side rendered page.

Comment: This is quite a topic for a different question. Everything depends on your use case. CDN's have a advantage of having multiple data center across the globe. This matters if your audience is spread across the globe (Europe/Asia-Australia, North/East America etc.)

Comment: Oh, okie. Thanks.